# How to create a simple array from another array whose values are in a range

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter

i have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5-6
    [1] => 8-12
    [2] => 13-15
)
```

And i need to create a new array as follows

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 9
        [4] => 10
        [5] => 11
        [6] => 12
        [7] => 13
        [8] => 14
        [8] => 15

    )
```

I dont know where to start and how to use loop with explode to produce the resultant array. Any help?

Comment: You seem to have an idea of how to start this, but then haven't shown any coding attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple use range function :

```
$array = [
    '5-6',
    '8-12',
    '13-15',
];
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $startEnd = explode('-', $row);
    $result = array_merge($result, range($startEnd[0], $startEnd[1]));
}

var_dump($result);
```

But don't forget StackOverflow is not here to do work at your place, even on simple "scripts". Try it, and if you have a problem, ask a question with a problem, not with a "I need to do it"